# Oddness with simple CSS: .class:hover property is overridden by property of #child

Tags: css, hover, background-color

In Chrome and Firefox, the following doesn't have the desired effect:

```
<style>
    #hoverOnMe { background-color:orange; }
    .open:hover { background-color:lightblue; }
</style>

<div id='hoverOnMe' class='open'>HELLO</div>
```

The :hover doesn't work. The background remains orange on hovering.

However, each of the other three possible combinations (listing by id twice, listing by class twice, and listing by class followed by id) works.

Of course my actual project is a little more complicated than this example; I'd like to add an "open" class to every hoverable element.

What's going on here? What's the simplest workaround?

Comment: it's because of the higher specificity of `#hoverOnMe` over `.open:hover`, you can just prepend the `#hoverOnMe` to the second rule like this `#hoverOnMe.open:hover`

Comment: I though `:hover` had super high specificity... Weird for a state, to be less important than a static selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to add an "open" class to every hoverable element.

Well if this is the case *and* you expect the *same* behaviour for all elements,
then you could just use `!important`:

```
.open:hover { 
   background-color:lightblue!important;
}
```

Comment: No white space at all? =)